# d3 JSON topology file reading node properties

Tags: json, d3.js

Im new one in d3 an json, and I do not understand how to read Node x and y coordinates of the topology map, written in this format:

```
"node": [
                {
                    "id": "MPLS-Node-A",
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "key": "label",
                            "Text": "MPLS-Node-A"
                        }, {
                            "key": "Host_IP",
                            "Text": "10.10.20.3"
                        }, {
                            "key": "size",
                            "Text": 10.0
                        }, {
                            "key": "r",
                            "Text": 153
                        }, {
                            "key": "g",
                            "Text": 153
                        }, {
                            "key": "b",
                            "Text": 153
                        }, {
                            "key": "x",
                            "Text": 521
                        }, {
                            "key": "y",
                            "Text": 104
                        }
                    ]
```

Thank U for any help!

Comment: You better reformat your JSON so that `x`, `y` etc are keys.

Comment: Yes, I think about it too. Actually, it was a result of converting GRAPHML to JSON by Altova XMLSpy